# Nginx permission error on try and index (actual file works fine)

Tags: nginx

I have nginx installed via Homebrew on my Mac. I recently tried to add a virtual php server. It works fine when I access the correct file name, but gives a permission error when the try block would be called or an index file should be served.

```
#200 :
http://php-sandbox.dev/index.php
#404 :
http://php-sandbox.dev/index
http://php-sandbox.dev/
```

The file index.php exists in the root web directory and has 744 permissions as do all folders in its path.

The index directive is apparently being ignored. See examples and errors below as well as my nginx config.

The site config file for nginx:
    server {
        listen      80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/php-sandbox/error.log debug;
        rewrite_log on;

```
    server_name php-sandbox.dev;

    root        /Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public;
    index       index.php index.html;

    include drop.conf; #ignores favicons

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Error log: (/ requested)

```
2017/04/23 09:47:15 [crit] 11149#0: *9 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
2017/04/23 09:47:15 [crit] 11149#0: *9 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
2017/04/23 09:47:15 [crit] 11149#0: *9 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
```

The try block is executing, but the index is not being attempted.

Error log: (/index requested)

```
2017/04/23 10:11:40 [crit] 11149#0: *12 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/index" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
2017/04/23 10:11:40 [crit] 11149#0: *12 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/index.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
2017/04/23 10:11:40 [crit] 11149#0: *12 stat() "/Users/sswright/repos/jswright61/php-sandbox/public/index" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: php-sandbox.dev, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "php-sandbox.dev"
```

Here it is looking for index.php but getting a permission error. When /index.php is requested, the page loads properly.

Comment: The URI `/index` should cause it to download `index.php`. Are you sure that this is the current `nginx` configuration? Test it using `nginx -T`

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the current config is active and it passes when I run nginx -t.